# How should UX designers review the completed web application and prepare a report about it?

Tags: usability, web-app, user-research, expert-review

How Should a UX designer review the completed app? What are the main credentials and How do you report if something is not working like expected? Do you have some check-list during your review or a template to write a report about the issues with the app? I'm looking for a path/suggestion to follow. Is there any source that can help me to review the app?

For instance, let's say all requirements covered. Does it mean the app is perfect from the UX perspective? Is there anything method to check the usability of the app? For the reporting part, Do you use any template to report issues such as interactions are not following the design or There are missing validations on some control?

Comment: You are asking quite a few questions here, so it would probably help to focus on the main problem you want to address or answered by the community. Also, it would be helpful to provide information on what your proposed plan is or how you want to approach the task, and then you will be able to get suggestions and ideas.

Comment: I've added more details to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I got the idea or aim of the question you ask, there's no proper way or a list containing all these phases in a single sheet as I know of. Rather there are several sources which doesn't make one of them over the other but preferably choosen.

Since I'm mostly into academical part of the topic these days, I can provide a couple of example scales below which you may consider or be aware of at least. With [Christian Rohrer's article from NN/g](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/which-ux-research-methods/) briefly explains methods to research, I mostly ran into the examples of usability scales below;

> - [User Experience Questionnaire](https://www.ueq-online.org)
> - Very common one is IBM's [CSUQ (Computer System Usability Questionnaires)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=2ahUKEwjXp7XayZbmAhWURhUIHcU2CRwQFjAMegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.isislab.it%2Fdelmal%2FMTAP%2FQuestionnaires%2FCSUQ.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ArKr7sQOBqX5Cg7pHrmOf),
> - Here is actually more than CSUQ [like SUS, etc.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10447318.2017.1418805?journalCode=hihc20),
> - Alternative as a [mobile solution](https://toad.halileksi.net/sites/default/files/pdf/mobil-uygulama-kullanilabilirlik-olcegi-toad.pdf),
> - There are lots of usability scales which all of them presented in Turkish but also with their abstracts so anyone can trace cited sources ([source - 1](https://toad.halileksi.net/sites/default/files/pdf/system-usability-scale-toad.pdf), [source - 2](https://toad.halileksi.net/sites/default/files/pdf/web-sitesi-kullanilabilirlik-olcegi-toad.pdf), [source - 3](https://toad.halileksi.net/sites/default/files/pdf/web-sitesi-kullanilabilirlik-duzeyi-olcegi-toad.pdf)),
> - And the last one is considering [e-service quality](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.576.4147&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex question.

The simplest review would be to test how quickly a user can find the relative information and to notice the pain points.  This information is now a baseline for future enhancements as well as providing user stories for your backlog.

The more complex answer depends upon what your goals were before you started the app. If you didn't have any benchmarks; if you didn't have pain points you were specifically trying to solve (example: your earlier / competitor's app has pain points x, y and z and your primary goal was to eliminate them) then there is little for you to measure.

Your reports are comparisons of a user's time, steps, frustration of "this" versus "that". If you have nothing to compare to you don't have anything to report on.  Now you're stuck doing a simple review of pain points, etc...

Comment: I agree with you on some points but as this is a completed application and designed by UI/UX. We have already pointed out all the pain points before delivering the designs and requirements to the dev team. Sometimes They're not following designs and the interactions. Now I've asked to review the app by my manager and prepare a report.  So far I've seen some missing things. How can I report them?

Comment: @MertCanKarakuş - One aspect to include in the report are all the differences between the design and what was produced.  You could propose doing A/B testing comparing the design and production; also find out why the developers changed the design without getting a sign-off from UX. If it was a time crunch find out what made the developer's version easier to build and then you can give a cost to business. If you want to change designs it will cost x hours of dev and QA resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize problems found with how much frustration they bring for the user, and how easy are they are solvable. Google for "UX Prio Matrix". Ideally you should do testing, and that's pretty wide topic :)

Comment: I feel like rather than just telling us to google it, you could explain the matrix in one or two sentences and an image, then the answer would be more deserving of upvotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goals, you can look at the screen and squint a bit (let your eyes go out of focus) to see which part of the screen stands out. It may be a call to action button you want people to click, it may be an image or video, it may be a form. Whatever action you want users in your site to take.

Try to remove or reduce distracting elements - like multiple buttons. You can use a text link for a secondary action.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you mapped out your Users Goals during your research?

Try getting a few people and ask them to perform tasks or actions on your app that are important and see how well they handle it and see if they get stuck.

Try get some help from the marketing team with a controlled [market test](https://www.mbaskool.com/business-concepts/marketing-and-strategy-terms/13681-simulated-test-market.html) to see if your users needs have been met.

Comment: All user goals are mapped, I'm mainly interested in checking and the reporting part. How do you check the app itself? For instance, let's say all requirements covered? Does it mean the app is perfect from the UX perspective? Is there anything method to check the usability of the app? For the reporting part, Do you use any template to report issues such as interactions are not following the design or There are some missing validations on controls?

Comment: @MertCanKarakuş I think the ISO 9241-210 has some templates but that book 'About Face, The Essentials of Interface design if I remember right has a good checklist in it somewhere. Why don't you try doing multiple rounds of usability testing and just release it. Then try more until it's good enough. Like t'was said, good design is never done. And it's hard to find all UX issues yourself, the user has to encounter it and bring it up so you can keep improving their experience...unknown unknowns...

Comment: Thanks for the book advice!